# Titanium.Network.HTTPClient caches responseData. How do I prevent that?

Tags: android, caching, titanium

I was wondering how to prevent `Titanium.Network.HTTPClient` from caching my `responseData`? This is happening on android in the directory `/sdcard/Android/data/com.packagename/cache/_tmp` the files follow this pattern for their filename `tihttp-XXXXXXXXXXXtmp`. I've already implemented a custom cache in the apps private data directory. So I don't need it to happen twice and waste the users precious data space on their sdcard. Plus the cache in the sdcard isn't always there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
     onload : function(e) {
         Ti.API.info("Received text: " + this.responseText);
         alert('success');
     },
     timeout : 5000,
     cache : false,

 });
```

The above works for iPhone only after a bit of looking, but if you set the headers directly to the request, it should work for both iPhone and Android:

```
client.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control','no-cache');
client.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control','no-store');
```

This must be called after open, but before the request is sent, i.e.:

```
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
client.open('GET','http://google.com/');
client.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control','no-cache');
client.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control','no-store');
client.send('nice');
```

Comment: In the docs it says that the cache properties default is false. So would it matter if I explicitly declare the cache property?